# Issue with QT and cross-compiling from Mac to Raspbian Stretch(RPi3)

Tags: qt, makefile, raspberry-pi

I'm following QT's documentation here to the letter: https://wiki.qt.io/RaspberryPi2EGLFS but I am constantly running into the same issue on my mac on Step 10.

I am running the following command:

```
./configure -release -opengl es2 -device linux-rasp-pi3-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=~/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- -sysroot ~/raspi/sysroot -opensource -confirm-license -make libs -prefix /usr/local/qt5pi -extprefix ~/raspi/qt5pi -hostprefix ~/raspi/qt5 -no-use-gold-linker -v
```

I get the following error:

```
Project ERROR: Cannot run compiler '/home/jordan/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++'. Maybe you forgot to setup the environment?
```

I have been fighting this tooth and nail and I cannot find an answer online, so I'm someone here may have an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The cross-compilation toolchain Raspberry Pi provides is probably built for Linux host systems. You need to use a toolchain built for macOS hosts, such as this one [here](https://github.com/Illuminux/ct-ng-linaro-mac).